# Array of UIColor subscript issue

Tags: arrays, swift, uicolor

I have this array of `UIColors` here

```
let newLayer = CALayer()

let barColors = [
    //Red
    UIColor(red: 0.969, green: 0.49, blue: 0.443, alpha: 1),
    //Orange
    UIColor(red: 0.984, green: 0.647, blue: 0.431, alpha: 1),
    //Pink
    UIColor(red: 0.894, green: 0.592, blue: 0.698, alpha: 1),
    //Purple
    UIColor(red: 0.851, green: 0.6, blue: 0.957, alpha: 1),
    //Yellow
    UIColor(red: 0.98, green: 0.875, blue: 0.455, alpha: 1),
    //Green
    UIColor(red: 0.49, green: 0.792, blue: 0.616, alpha: 1),
    //Blue
    UIColor(red: 0.553, green: 0.71, blue: 0.906, alpha: 1)]
```

When I try to assign my `newLayer` background color to one of the `UIColors` in the array with this:

```
newLayer.backgroundColor = barColors[0]
```

I get an error saying `cannot subscript a value of type '[UIColor]'`. Any ideas why I am getting this error and how to fix it?

Comment: `CALayers`s `backgroundColor` property is a `CGColor`, not a `UIColor`

Comment: I'm really curious as to why the Swift compiler thinks it is a problem with subscripts... Perhaps it thinks the programmer can "modify" to code of Swift's struct `Array<T>` so that its `subscript` returns the expected instances of `CGColor`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is misleading. `backgroundColor` property of `CALayer` expects value of type `CGColor` not `UIColor`.

You can get `CGColor` value from `UIColor`:

```
newLayer.backgroundColor = barColors[0].CGColor
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
newLayer.backgroundColor = barColors[0].CGColor
```

because `CALayer's` `backgroundColor` property accepts `CGColor` value instead of `UIColor`

Answer (score -1):

Try This One, I think it will help you if you want to set background color of viewcontroller's view.

```
let newLayer = CALayer()

    let barColors = [
        //Red
        UIColor(red: 0.969, green: 0.49, blue: 0.443, alpha: 1),
        //Orange
        UIColor(red: 0.984, green: 0.647, blue: 0.431, alpha: 1),
        //Pink
        UIColor(red: 0.894, green: 0.592, blue: 0.698, alpha: 1),
        //Purple
        UIColor(red: 0.851, green: 0.6, blue: 0.957, alpha: 1),
        //Yellow
        UIColor(red: 0.98, green: 0.875, blue: 0.455, alpha: 1),
        //Green
        UIColor(red: 0.49, green: 0.792, blue: 0.616, alpha: 1),
        //Blue
        UIColor(red: 0.553, green: 0.71, blue: 0.906, alpha: 1)]
    self.viewIfLoaded?.backgroundColor = barColors[0]; // index for color
```

Also  if you want to setbackground color for the layer of view then find the below code will help

```
newLayer.backgroundColor = barColors[0].CGColor;
```